# iOS Linker Error Unable to Find File

Tags: ios, linker-errors, mach-o

I've got this error that doesn't occur on my machine in the file it was originally created in...However, when I upload to GitHub and try it on another machine, this linker error occurs.  I have no idea how to fix it because I don't really know what it is looking for except for a file that I believed was built when you compiled the program.  Here is a snapshot of the error.

[image: Error]

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue that was a result of renaming the project.  I just named it back to the original name and everything was fine.